# Should I use .eq(0) when using the $("body") selector?

Tags: jquery

Is there any benefit (performance or otherwise) for me to use the .eq(0) filter when I reference the body tag in a jQuery object? For instance: **$("body").eq(0)** as opposed to just **$("body")**.

Comment: The only optimization that could be made is $(document.body), anything else is nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `$("body")` should do just fine.. `eq(0)` is just to pick the first element and it won't make any difference if it has just one element to begin with.

`$('body')` will have the same structure as `$('body').eq(0)` but `.eq` is just an extra call.

`.eq` function implementation

```
function (i) {
    i = +i;
    return i === -1 ? this.slice(i) : this.slice(i, i + 1);
}
```

As you see, it doesn't make sense to do a `eq` when you just have only one element.

Comment: `eq(0)` returns the html element whereas `$("body")` returns a jQuery object, so they're a little different. *edit*. I'm wrong. I was thinking about `.get(0)`.

Comment: @JimSchubert Nope.. You are confusing `.get` with `.eq`

Answer (score 0):

Nope it does not make any difference , on the contrary there is an extra call on the element and jquery constructs the same element once again. This will be an overhead if performance is any consideration.

Comment: I don't think it constructs an new jQuery object.. it simply slice the array.. same with `gt`, `lt`, `first`, `last`.

Comment: "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set." ref:http://api.jquery.com/eq/  . From this I interpreted that a new object is created, please correct me if I am wrong.